# Difference between JSON-RPC Endpoints of BSC, https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443 vs https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/?

Tags: web3js, json-rpc

I was still doing well with JSON-RPC Endpoint (https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443) from https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/rpc.html; normally it's only about 5X,XXX

```
var web3 = new Web3('https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443');
var web3 = new Web3('https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/');
```

But today Gas Limit is too high (81,344), so I tried to lookup many and found some endpoints, one of them: https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/

With same contract, same data & nonce, I used **web3.eth.estimateGas** then Gas Limit of the new one is 22,848; it's just same to fee for BNB transfer.

Why they have too different fees like that, someone may help me understand?

It's safe to use with the new one?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545 is testnet rpc !
Use it if you wanna test stuff without burning "real" BNB for gas (testnet bnb has no value lol).

Have a nice day :D